# How to authenticate dedicated devices using Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, android-management-api

I got a couple of dedicated devices using the Android Management API and those devices need to access my AppEngine Endpoints, Cloud Storage etc.  In my Kiosk App I'm currently using the Firebase AuthUi(Google Sign-in) and initially login to all devices with the same gmail address. 
Is there a way to authenticate my devices with Firebase that doesn't require me to manually sign in with the same gmail to every device?

Comment: There is no per-device authentication offered by Firebase.  The best you can do is bake some email/password credentials into your app for login, and hope that no one is able to get that APK.

Comment: Could anonymous authentication be an option? Take a look at the official documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth?hl=en